# Auto rickshaw battery

Tags: battery

Can anybody help me in **battery selection for auto rickshaw** ? My engine is CNG engine suitable for 3 wheeler auto rickshaw.
1) My current requirements are= 23.6A (Vehicle+Engine required electrical load) at 90 degree temperature. This 23.6A is calculated from charge balance of electrical load.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What kind of engine does your rickshaw have? At 12V, 23.6A is enough to start a 50 or maybe 125cc engine, but bigger engines will likely draw more current.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the current draw you've already calculated (which is actually more useful for alternator sizing), you will need three other bits of information:

- Cold Cranking Amps (CCA) - this is how much current is needed to start the engine (unless it has a kick-start? I'm not familiar with auto-rickshaws) - this is usually higher than the amount needed to keep everything going.
- Amp-hours - this is how much charge is stored in the battery, for example a 50AH battery could provide 10A for 5 hours before running out.
- Dimensions - the size of the space in which the battery has to fit, and the layout of the terminals.

Once you've got these, your local battery supplier should be able to provide something suitable - we can't help there!

Bear in mind that if you're upgrading to a bigger battery because you've added more accessories to the vehicle, you will probably need a bigger alternator/generator to charge it and keep the accessories going - in fact I'd do that first...